# CodeIgniter model

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter

I'm working on my first large CodeIgniter project (and one of my first MVC projects), and I want to get some feedback on the techniques I've used so far in one of my models:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model_programs extends SOA_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     *
     * Returns an array of all programs owned by a user.
     *
     * @param int         $user_id User ID to query.
     * @return bool|array          Array of user's programs or FALSE.
     */
    function user_programs($user_id){
        if(!is_numeric($user_id)) return FALSE;
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT programs.id, programs.name
                                    FROM programs
                                    INNER JOIN program_users
                                    ON program_users.program_id = programs.id
                                    WHERE program_users.user_id = :user_id");

        $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $sth->execute();
        $user_programs = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$user_programs) return FALSE;

        $return = array();

        foreach($user_programs as $program){
            $return[$program['id']] = $program['name'];
        }

        return $return;

    }

    /**
     *
     * Creates a new program owned by a user.
     *
     * @param int       $user_id              ID of user to own the program.
     * @param string    $program_name         Name of program to create, max 255 chars. Must be unique to the user.
     * @param string    $program_description  Description of program, max 2000 chars.
     * @param string    $program_logo         Location and filename of uploaded logo.
     * @return bool|int                       Program ID or FALSE.
     */
    function create_program($user_id, $program_name, $program_description, $program_logo){
        if(!is_numeric($user_id)) return FALSE;

        //Check if the user already owns a program of that name
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT programs.id
                                    FROM programs
                                    INNER JOIN program_users
                                    ON program_users.program_id = programs.id
                                    WHERE program_users.user_id = :user_id
                                    AND programs.name = :program_name");
        $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $sth->bindParam(':program_name', $program_name);
        $sth->execute();

        if($sth->fetch()) return FALSE;

        //Create a new record in the programs table
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO programs (name, description, logo)
                                    VALUES (:name, :description, :logo)");
        $sth->bindParam(':name', $program_name);
        $sth->bindParam(':description', $program_description);
        $sth->bindParam(':logo', $program_logo);

        if(!$sth->execute()) return FALSE;

        //Get the ID of the new program
        $program_id = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();

        if(!$this->add_program_user($program_id, $user_id, 1)){ //Problem here
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM programs
                                        WHERE program_id = :program_id");
            $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
            $sth->execute();

            return FALSE;
        }

        return (int)$program_id;
    }

    /**
     * Add a user to a program. If user already exists on
     * program, their user type will be updated.
     *
     * @param int $program_id   ID of program to add user to.
     * @param int $user_id      ID of user.
     * @param int $user_type_id ID of user type for user on program.
     * @return bool
     */
    function add_program_user($program_id, $user_id, $user_type_id){
        if(!is_numeric($program_id) || !is_numeric($user_id) || !is_numeric($user_type_id)) return FALSE;

        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT *
                                    FROM program_users
                                    WHERE program_id = :program_id
                                    AND user_id = :user_id");
        $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
        $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $sth->execute();

        if($sth->fetch()){
            //Update existing record in the program_users table
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE program_users
                                        SET user_type = :user_type_id
                                        WHERE program_id = :program_id
                                        AND user_id = :user_id");
            $sth->bindParam(':user_type_id', $user_type_id);
            $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);

            if(!$sth->execute()) return FALSE;
        }else{
            //Create a new record in the program_users table
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO program_users (program_id, user_id, user_type)
                                        VALUES (:program_id, :user_id, :user_type)");
            $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_type', $user_type_id);

            if(!$sth->execute()) return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Remove specified user from program.
     *
     * @param  int $program_id Program to remove user from.
     * @param  int $user_id    User to remove.
     * @return bool
     */
    function remove_program_user($program_id, $user_id){
        if(!is_numeric($program_id) || !is_numeric($user_id)) return FALSE;

        #$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM program_users
        #                            WHERE program_id = :program_id
        #                            AND user_id = :user_id");
    }

    /**
     * Gets program name from program ID.
     *
     * @param int         $program_id ID of program to query.
     * @return bool|string             Program name or FALSE.
     */
    function program_name($program_id){
        if(!is_numeric($program_id)) return FALSE;
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT name
                                    FROM programs
                                    WHERE id = :id");
        $sth->bindParam(':id', $program_id);
        $sth->execute();

        $program = $sth->fetch();

        if(!$program) return FALSE;

        return $program['name'];
    }

    /**
     * Gets program ID from program name and user ID.
     *
     * @param string    $program_name Name of program to look up.
     * @param int       $user_id      ID of user who owns the program.
     * @return bool|int               ID of program owned by user.
     */
    function program_id($program_name, $user_id){
        if(!is_string($program_name) || !is_numeric($user_id)) return FALSE;
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT programs.id
                                    FROM programs
                                    INNER JOIN program_users
                                    ON program_users.program_id = programs.id
                                    WHERE programs.name = :program_name
                                    AND program_users.user_id = :user_id");
        $sth->bindParam(':program_name', $program_name);
        $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $sth->execute();
        $program = $sth->fetch();

        if(!$program) return FALSE;
        return (int)$program['id'];

    }

    /**
     *
     * Get users associated with a program ID.
     *
     * @param  int        $program_id ID of program.
     * @return bool|array             Array of user IDs.
     */
    function program_users($program_id){
        if(!is_numeric($program_id)) return FALSE;
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id
                                    FROM program_users
                                    WHERE program_id = :program_id");
        $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
        $sth->execute();
        $program_users = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $program_users;
    }

    /**
     * @param int       $program_id ID of program.
     * @param int       $user_id    ID of user.
     * @return bool|int             ID of user type or FALSE if user does not exist
     *                              on program.
     */
    function program_user_type($program_id, $user_id){
        if(!is_int($program_id) || !is_numeric($user_id)) return FALSE;
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT user_type
                                    FROM program_users
                                    WHERE program_id = :program_id
                                    AND user_id = :user_id");
        $sth->bindParam(':program_id', $program_id);
        $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
        $sth->execute();
        $program = $sth->fetch();

        if(!$program) return FALSE;
        return (int)$program['user_type'];
    }

}
```

This is still a work in progress so many things are subject to change, but overall am I utilizing MVC correctly (as far as you can tell from this code, at least)? I'm sure I'm doing a few things that I don't need to do, and possibly not doing some things that I should be doing?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific reason that you don't use Active Record?

For example:

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT programs.id, programs.name
                            FROM programs
                            INNER JOIN program_users
                            ON program_users.program_id = programs.id
                            WHERE program_users.user_id = :user_id");

$sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$sth->execute();
$user_programs = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This can be done like the following with AR, and it looks cleaner to me. This is probably personal preference.

```
$user_programs = $this->dbh->select('programs.id, programs.name')
                           ->from('programs')
                           ->join('program_users', 'programs.id = program_users.id', 'inner')
                           ->where('program_users.user_id', $user_id)
                           ->get()
                           ->result();
```

You can use `result_array()` as well if you want the results in array format.

Comment: I prefer PDO mainly because I have more experience with it, and I like to write actual SQL queries. Thanks for the input though.